# Lizmap legend layer

Tags: getlegendgraphic, lizmap

I'm trying to redirect GetLegendGraphics to another url. I changed LegendUrl in properties layer in QGIS :

[image]

My Request=GetCapabilities shows the good link to my legend :

```
<Style>
  <Name>défaut</Name>
  <Title>défaut</Title>
  <LegendURL>
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://mydomain/media/themes/default/css/img/legend.png>
  </LegendURL>
</Style>
```

But in Lizmap, legend still the legend of the layer...
Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, lizmap does not use legendURL. This feature has not been requested. Can you open a feature request ? https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues

Comment: Ok I opened a new feature request https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/1571.